# Invalid expression term '&&'

Tags: c#

I copy the code straight out of the text book and it doesn't work.

Here's the code:

```
public void BinarySearch(int[] numlist, int value)
    {
        int min = 0;
        int max = numlist.Length - 1;
        int index = -1;

        while (min <= && index == -1)
        {
            int mid = (min + max) / 2;
            if (value > numlist[mid])
            {
                min = mid + 1;
            }
            else if ( value< numlist[mid])
            {
                max = mid - 1;
            }
            else
            {
                index = mid;
            }
        }
        return index;
    }
```

The error I get is:

> "Invalid expression term '&&'"

What have I done wrong? I have battled this before and not found an answer for it on StackOverflow.

Comment: `while (min <= && index == -1)` after `<=` you are missing another operand.

Comment: You have `min <=`, but what should `min` be less than or equal to?

Comment: You should take your textbook and look again if you have typed the line correctly. The outcome could be a) you have typed it incorrectly, question closed as typo, b) the textbook has a typo, question closed as for a)

Comment: If you have copied this method i wonder what went wrong. Why you don't  compare it with the original, working version?

Answer (score 1):

You want to compare `min` with `max` not `&&` and that condition have two part 
then the code would be (from what I am seeing `BainarySearch`):

```
public void BinarySearch(int[] numlist, int value)
    {
        int min = 0;
        int max = numlist.Length - 1;
        int index = -1;

        while (min <=max && index == -1)
        {
            int mid = (min + max) / 2;
            if (value > numlist[mid])
            {
                min = mid + 1;
            }
            else if ( value< numlist[mid])
            {
                max = mid - 1;
            }
            else
            {
                index = mid;
            }
        }
        return index;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a value in your `while` condition:

```
while (min <= [here goes your value] && index == -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

problem is min <= ? what

while (min <= && index == -1)